# remove the profile but the camera always be disabled

Tags: python, iphone, mdm

I have a strange problem at my iphone, 
when  I remove the mdm profile, 
the camera always be disabled, it's not come back , the mdm profile is only one , how to reset it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remove the Profile from the Device settings or through the Apple Configurator?
Many times even if you remove profile from Device settings, its still there in the Device.
You can see if its still there in the Device using Apple Configurator and try removing it from there.

Comment: I used the Apple Configurator but could not see any profile, the final solution is the phone restore, it seem to be apple's bug.

Comment: @LuffyMchd Ok great ! Thanks for Sharing